# How to show percentage (text) next to the horizontal bars in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using seaborn's countplot to show count distribution of 2 categorical data. Fine it works but I want the percentages to show on top of the bars for each of the plot. Please how do I do it?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sns.countplot(y = df['current_status'], ax=ax[0]).set_title('Current Occupation')
sns.countplot(df['gender'], ax=ax[1]).set_title('Gender distribution')
```

[image]

I have made edits based on the comments made but I can't get the percentages to the right of horizontal bars. This is what I have done.

```
total = len(df['current_status'])*1.
ax = sns.countplot(y="current_status", data=df)
plt.title('Distribution of  Configurations')
plt.xlabel('Number of Axles')

for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate('{:.1f}%'.format(100*p.get_height()/total), (p.get_y()+0.1, p.get_height()+5))
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(map('{:.1f}%'.format, 100*ax.xaxis.get_majorticklocs()/total))
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179122/seaborn-countplot-with-frequencies

Comment: @Alexis, please I have made edits to the question.

Comment: @Esmailian I have made some edits but I still have some issues. Please take a look.

Comment: It is better to say "I want the percentages to the right of horizontal bars"

Comment: @Esmailian I have edited it Sir. So whats the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example to add a text to the right of horizontal bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a'], ['a'], ['b']]), columns=['current_status'])
ax = sns.countplot(y="current_status", data=df)
plt.title('Distribution of  Configurations')
plt.xlabel('Number of Axles')

total = len(df['current_status'])
for p in ax.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_width()/total)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() + 0.02
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y))

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

You can move the texts around by changing the formula for `x` and `y`. For example, to place them on top:

```
x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
y = p.get_y() - 0.02
```

Here is a general guideline for [annotating axes](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
# plot1 real 

fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize =(12,40))
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.set_context('notebook')
#sns.set(font_scale=2)
plt.fontsize =(35)

ax=sns.barplot( palette="Dark2",ax=ax,

            x='square km', y='state',data=d)
total=len(d['state'])
for p in ax.patches:
    percentage ='{:,.0f}KM²'.format(p.get_width())
    width, height =p.get_width(),p.get_height()
    x=p.get_x()+width+0.02
    y=p.get_y()+height/2
    ax.annotate(percentage,(x,y))

plt.xticks(rotation =50,fontsize =18)
plt.yticks(rotation =50,fontsize =20)

plt.title('NIGERIA\'S 36 STATES & FCT RANKED\n IN ORDER OF LAND SURFACE AREA (KM²)',
         fontsize =30 
         )
plt.xlabel ('SQUARE KM',fontsize =24)
plt.ylabel ('STATE',fontsize =24)

plt.show ()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Data Science StackExchange. Please consider improving your answer by adding a comment to the suggested code.